# Failure to Redirect on user Sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, redirect

I have a rails app . I have created a sessionscontroller and want to redirect to users page '/users' once the user signs in. But the redirect doesnt seem to be happening.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
     user = User.find_or_create_by_fbid(params[:user][:fbid]) #...Success
     user.update_attributes(params[:user])  #....Sucess
     sign_in(user)  # ....This occurs successfully 
     redirect_to users_path # .... Redirect doesnt occur on the browser side 
  end

end
```

The sign_in method is defined inside the Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:fbid] = user.fbid
    @current_user = user
  end

end
```

Server Logs below . The redirect actually seems to be happening on the server side . But I do not see any change on the client side. The browser doesnt change page.

[image: Server Logs]

The UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  end
```

Original Ajax Post -

```
$.post("/sessions",{user:{name:profile.name, email:profile.email,fbid:profile.id}});
```

The redirect occurs successfully if I use a javascript redirect statement inside the $post() as a callback function .

```
$.post("/sessions",{user:{name:profile.name, email:profile.email,fbid:profile.id}},function( data ) {
          window.location="/users";
      }
    );
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is cause of the issue, but redirect should point to absolute URL, not relative one (so, you need to use ` redirect_to users_url`).  Also, your controller code looks very optimistic.

Comment: Thanks . But changing it to users_url did not help .I just edited the question to add an extract from the UsersController.

Comment: @mad.geek: this is a facebook signin right? Is it occurring via AJAX or standard HTML posts?

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott  - Yes it is Facebook Sign in . The session#create ( Sign in ) is happening via an AJAX post after the user  authenticates via Facebook. Are redirects not possible after AJAX POSTs ?

Comment: I added the AJAX code in the question.

Comment: The issue seems to get fixed if I do a javascript redirect via a callback function inside the $post().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the response's redirection in an ajax query. Normally the browser handles, but it won't with ajax.

From this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) (edited slightly for your case)

```
var params = {user:{name:profile.name, email:profile.email,fbid:profile.id}};
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/sessions",
data: params,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data, textStatus) {
    if (data.redirect) {
        // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
    }
    else {
        // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
        $("#login_form").replaceWith(data.form);
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Yup. Got it . Thanks !! Any idea why redirect doesnt work  in case of Ajax calls ?

Comment: @mad.geek -- the browser isn't making the request, the javascript objects are -- and they don't redirect by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a real basic authentication based of Ryan Bates' screencast. If you can't figure it out from my code, I recommend watching [Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch)

applications_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.eb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Ajax Post -

```
$.post("/sessions",{user:{name:profile.name, email:profile.email,fbid:profile.id}});
```

Comment: If we take the bare bones, both are codes are the same. While you do a redirect to root_url , I am trying to do a redirect to users_url .